# Determining solution of Riccati equations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given are a $\mathbb{C}$-valued function $\phi$, $\mathbb{C}^d$-valued function $\psi$, $\mathcal{X}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and the following differential equation, which holds for all $x \in \mathcal{X},\ T \geq 0,\ u \in \mathrm{i}\mathbb{R}^{d}$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{T} \phi(T, u)+\partial_{T} \psi(T, u)^{\top} x&=\psi(T, u)^{\top} b(x)+\frac{1}{2} \psi(T, u)^{\top} a(x) \psi(T, u)\\
\psi(0,u)&=u\\
\phi(0,u)&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, the author states the following:

> Since $\psi(0, u)=u$, this implies that $a$ and $b$ are of the form
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &a(x)=A+\sum_{i=1}^{d} x_{i} \alpha_{i} \\
> &b(x)=B+\sum_{i=1}^{d} x_{i} \beta_{i}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> for some $d \times d$-matrices $A$ and $\alpha_{i}$, and $d$-vectors $B$ and $\beta_{i}$. Plugging this back into the above equation yields the Riccati equations
> \begin{aligned}
> \partial_{t} \phi(t, u) &=\frac{1}{2} \psi(t, u)^{\top} A\  \psi(t, u)+B^{\top} \psi(t, u) \\
> \phi(0, u) &=0 \\
> \partial_{t} \psi_{i}(t, u) &=\frac{1}{2} \psi(t, u)^{\top} \alpha_{i} \psi(t, u)+\beta_{i}^{\top} \psi(t, u), \quad 1 \leq i \leq d \\
> \psi(0, u) &=u
> \end{aligned}

For $T=0$, I find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{T} \phi(0, u)+\partial_{T} \psi(0, u)^{\top} x&=u^{\top} b(x)+\frac{1}{2} u^{\top} a(x) u\\
\end{aligned}
$$

But how do I find the form of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ from that? How do I find the Riccati equations?

The equation

$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_{T} \phi(T, u)+\partial_{T} \psi(T, u)^{\top} x&=\psi(T, u)^{\top} b(x)+\frac{1}{2} \psi(T, u)^{\top} a(x) \psi(T, u)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

reminds me on some sort of Taylor expansion. Maybe this could be used?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In a problem like this, why not tell us where it comes from?

Comment: It is from the proof of Theorem 2.2 in following Arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.4003v3